# LDAP get full name and email nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, active-directory

I am writing app in node js. For login I would like use active directory. I found this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2). Authentication is ok, but I cannot get user full name and email. There is my code:

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory2');
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory2');
var _ = require('underscore');
var query = 'cn=*Exchange*';
var opts = {
    includeMembership : [ 'all' ],
    includeDeleted : false
};
    var config = {
        url: 'ldap://dc.in.domain.cz',
        baseDN: 'CN=Users,DC=in,DC=domain,DC=cz',
        bindDN: 'CN=searchuser,CN=users,DC=in,DC=domain,DC=cz'
    };
    var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
    var username = 'username @in.domain.cz';
    var password = 'my_password';

    ad.authenticate(username, password, function (err, auth) {
        if (auth) {
        console.log('Authenticated!');
        ad.find(query, function (err, results) {
                if ((err) || (!results)) {
                    console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                    return;
                }

                console.log('Users');
                _.each(results.users, function (user) {
                    console.log('  ' + user.cn);
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Authentication failed!');
        }
    });
```

I get error:

```
ERROR: {"lde_message":"000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907C2, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580\u0000","lde_dn":null}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`authenticate`](https://github.com/jsumners/node-activedirectory#authenticate) function is just used for testing if credentials are valid. You would use this if, for example, you have a login page and you want to see if the credentials the user gave you are correct. These credentials are not used for the other operations.

In the documentation, it says under [the Usage heading](https://github.com/jsumners/node-activedirectory#usage):

> The username and password specified in the configuration are what are used for user and group lookup operations.

So when you use `find()`, it's using the credentials you put in `config`. You have `bindDN` there, but you don't have `password`, which is likely why the bind failed. You will need to add the password for that "searchuser" account:

```
var config = {
    url: 'ldap://dc.in.domain.cz',
    baseDN: 'CN=Users,DC=in,DC=domain,DC=cz',
    bindDN: 'CN=searchuser,CN=users,DC=in,DC=domain,DC=cz',
    password: 'something'
};
```

Note that the docs say that you can also use the `username` property instead of `bindDN`, but don't think there is any functional difference except being able to just specify the username and not the whole DN:

```
var config = {
    url: 'ldap://dc.in.domain.cz',
    baseDN: 'CN=Users,DC=in,DC=domain,DC=cz',
    username: 'searchuser@in.domain.cz',
    password: 'something'
};
```